# Rectangle remove side

Tags: java, itext, itextpdf

Is it possible to remove a side for a rectangle ?

I want draw a rectangle on my pdf page  without left side

`rect.disableBorderSide(Rectangle.LEFT);` does not works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`setBorder(int)`](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/Rectangle.html)

> Enables/Disables the border on the specified sides. The border is specified as an integer bitwise combination of the constants: LEFT, RIGHT, TOP, BOTTOM.

If other borders are active, just

```
rect.setBorder(Rectangle.LEFT);
```

will disable the **`LEFT`** side.

To understand the part:

> The border is specified as an integer bitwise combination of the constants: LEFT, RIGHT, TOP, BOTTOM.

If you want to set various just use `|` operator:

```
rect.setBorder(Rectangle.LEFT | Rectangle.TOP);
```

Comment: glad to help @Valeriane :)